# Folder listing with gsutil with condition

Tags: bash, ls, gsutil

I have got this: `gsutil ls -d gs://mystorage/*123*`,
which gives me all files matching the pattern "123".
I wonder if i could do this with condition like `>123` and `<127`. To grab all files whose names contain 124, 125 and 126.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other than `*`, `gsutil` supports [special](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/WildcardNames#other-wildcard-characters) wildcard names.
You can use these special wildcards to match the name of your files, but keep in mind that you are working with strings and characters rather than numbers, therefore the solution is not very straight forward. [Here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/numericranges.html) is a guide using regexp, that better explains how to work with digits, in a general way.

For your specific question, you would end up with something like:

```
gsutil ls -d gs://mystorage/*12[456]*
```